# Can my iot device publish message to AWS IoT core message broker without me registering the device and creating a thing or thing type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I just want to use AWS Iot Service for transport mechanism, where my IoT devices from several locations will publish a message to a topic and My Rule defined in AWS will read the topic messages and send it away to AWS Kinesis. This is my simple requirement. Any help or direction will be highly appreciated.

Updated Since:
This is what I did on the server side.

1. setup AWS IoT core with Custom Authorizer that calls Lambda service for Username/Password authentication.
2. Lamda Service returns a Policy upon authnetication.
3. Tested my Authorizer and it works.

> ```
> aws iot test-invoke-authorizer --authorizer-name MyAuthorizerName
> --mqtt-context username=sri,password=c3VkZGk=,clientId=sclera 
> "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":
>
> ], "refreshAfterInSeconds": 300, "disconnectAfterInSeconds": 86400 }
> { "isAuthenticated": true, "principalId": "sclera", "policyDocuments":
> [[{\"Action\":\"iot:*\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
> ```

Following is my Python Client code

```
import ssl
import time
import base64
import paho.mqtt.client as paho

connected = False

port = 8883
broker_address = "XXXXXXXXXX-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
certificate_path = "C:/Users/SridharKondoji/Desktop/Sclera/AmazonRootCA1.pem"


orig_username = "test_user"
orig_password = "123asdf!123"


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Client is connected")
        global connected
        connected = True
    else:
        print("Connection failed!")

def get_decoded_string(base64_string):
    base64_bytes = base64_string.encode("ascii")

    sample_string_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
    sample_string = sample_string_bytes.decode("ascii")
    return sample_string

def get_base64_string(username):
    username_string_bytes = username.encode("ascii")
    base64_username_bytes = base64.b64encode(username_string_bytes)
    base64_username_string = base64_username_bytes.decode("ascii")
    return base64_username_string


uname = get_base64_string(orig_username)
password = get_base64_string(orig_password)
client = paho.Client("MQTT")
client.tls_set(certificate_path)
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
client.username_pw_set(uname, password=password)
client.enable_logger()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(broker_address, port=port)

client.loop_start()
while connected != True:
    time.sleep(0.2)

client.publish("/house/bulb1", "Hello MQTT2 from paho")

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can have your clients authenticate with one of the supported mechanisms (IAM, certificates or custom authentication) and set an IoT Policy that defines on which topics the client can publish and/or subscribe.

The flow can be a bit complex when using IAM or certificates since you'll have to do an extra call to associate the client with an IoT Policy. When using custom authentication, this can be done in a single lambda. This [blogpost](https://medium.com/cloudway/customize-your-aws-iot-gateway-authentication-a0ac8ef5aa3d) shows how you can use custom authentication to achieve this. In the blogpost, the connection is made using MQTT over WebSockets, but the flow and logic hold for any other client connection mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and confirmation that I don't need to onboard devices. I am unable to successfully connect to my AWS IoT broker.
If you could look at my python client code and let me know, what's wrong, that would be great.  I am thinking that mqtt client code is not doing the right thing in my case.
Ant help here will be highly apprciated.

Comment: I tried port 443 and 8443, client couldn't connect. I tried port 8883 with  True/False for client.tls_insecure_set(), I got weird errors like Server closing the connections.

Comment: Could you try to use the aws it device sdk to setup the connection? The Python sdk can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2).

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this. The code I shared above worked with Mosquito Broker with a different root CA certificate. During my server configuration, I didn't add any certificates. I am assuming Amazon by defualt uses its TLS certificate. Correct?
I will try to use the sample python code using aws device sdk. 
I think most of the problems I ran into with my python code above is with certificate itself. I will add my comments after running the code.

Comment: AWS uses it's own certificates and has a custom signing certificate. You can find more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html)

Comment: Say, if you are using client/server mtls, can you still publish messages to aws iot broker without onboarding the devices? If yes, how will the device get the policy needed?

Comment: If you're using the X.509 certificates for authentication, you will manually have to associate a policy with the certificate after you have registered it on the AWS IoT Core.

Comment: Sorry @stijndepestel  I am travelling and will try this asap.

Comment: I looked at the python sdk and it allows only two options mtls or websockets. Both don't look like a viable option to me as I only want Server authentication by client and Client provide username/password. Client will not send any client certificate in its connect request to the broker.
My iot client should work like a browser. Is this possible?